# I need help simplifying some Javascript

Tags: javascript, calculator

I have some really overly-complicated javascript used to create many input fields and drop down boxes based on a number a user puts into a text-field.
 A basic description: it figures out if your using a number or not, then figures out if the number is less than five, then figures out which number it is. Then I copy and pasted the text-field and operations depending on what number it was. Obviously, I suck at Javascript(and proper grammar.)

Here's the code:

```
function calculator() {
var boxNumber= document.getElementById('boxNumber').value;
var boxInt= parseInt(boxNumber);
var limit= new Number(5);

if (Math.floor(boxInt)== boxInt) {

    if (boxInt <= limit) {

        x= boxInt;

        if (x==5){

            document.getElementById('opSpace').innerHTML="<br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select><br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select><br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select><br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select><br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select>"

        }

        else {

            if (x==4) {

                document.getElementById('opSpace').innerHTML="<br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select><br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select><br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select><br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select>"

            }

            else {

                if (x==3) {

                document.getElementById('opSpace').innerHTML="<br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select><br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select><br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select>"

            }

                else {

                    if (x==2) {

                        document.getElementById('opSpace').innerHTML="<br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select><br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select>"

                    }

                    else {

                    if (x==1) {

                        document.getElementById('opSpace').innerHTML="<br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select>"

                    }

                    else {

                        alert("No zeros or negatives please")

                    }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

    else {
    alert ("Use a number less than 5")
    }
}

else {
    alert("Use a number")
}
}
```

You get the idea. This is the precursor to a calculator where the text-fields will define operating numbers and the drop-downs will define operations. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by compressing the javascript?

Comment: making it less spacious

Comment: You just mean simplify it, and get rid of all the repetition?

Comment: yes i do. it would make my life a whole lot easier

Comment: How about using a `for` loop? If you want to repeat something `x` times, you write `for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function calculator() {
    var boxNumber = document.getElementById('boxNumber').value;
    var boxInt = Math.floor( parseInt(boxNumber, 10) );
    var limit = 5;
    var htmlString = '<br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select>';

    function repeatString(str, num) {
        return new Array(num + 1).join(str);
    }

    if ( !isNaN(boxInt) && boxInt <= limit && boxInt > 0 ) {
        document.getElementById('opSpace').innerHTML = repeatString( htmlString, boxInt );
    } else if (boxInt < 0) {
        alert('Use a number between 0-' + limit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function calculator() {
    var boxNumber= document.getElementById('boxNumber').value;
    var boxInt= parseInt(boxNumber, 10);
    var limit= 5;

    if (Math.floor(boxInt)== boxInt) {
        if (boxInt <= limit && boxInt > 0) {
            var html = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < boxInt; i++) {
                html += "<br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select>";
            }
            document.getElementById('opSpace').innerHTML = html;
        } else {
            alert("No zeros or negatives please")
        }
    } else {
        alert ("Use a number less than 5")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
if(x>limit)
{
     ... show error...
}
else if(x<= 0)
{
     ... show error...
}
else
{
    var el = document.getElementById('opSpace');
    el.innerHTML = '';
    for(var i = 0; i<x; i++)
    {
        el.innerHTML += "<br /><input /><p></p><select><option>Add</option><option>Sub</option><option>Mul</option><option>Div</option></select>";
    }
}
```